# mkswap complains that partition is misaligned (LVM on RAID-0)

Tags: linux, lvm, raid, swap, raid0

I have a RAID-0 setup on two identical hard disks (same brand and model). The partition table is identical on both (I have cloned it). However, `/dev/md0` occupies only part of the disks, because I had to do some juggling with data I had on a previous installation, so I could not just wipe out everything.

Anyway, I set up LVM on `md0`, and created some logical volumes, including one for swap. But when I use `mkswap`, it complains about the partition being misaligned:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/vg000/swap
mkswap: warning: /dev/vg000/swap is misaligned
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 8 GiB (8589930496 bytes)
```

Am I supposed to worry about this? If it only means some Mb of swap won't be usable, that's fine. But if it means I may have memory corruption because swapping won't work properly, then, obviously, I'd like to know how to fix it!

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning based on [information provided by the kernel](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/ad553030fbaa2654e3ec8e9524b096eae6b57b21/lib/blkdev.c#L240). Misalignment mostly has performance impacts; on SSDs it may result in additional wear. It won't cause corruption!

[Software RAID 10 + LVM on mixed drives, sector alignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115294/software-raid-10-lvm-on-mixed-drives-sector-alignment) has lots of useful information on this, including recipes to set things up correctly.